# mongo insert into array at top without duplicates

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update an array of ids with an additional item but I require the following:
1. if it exists then obviously it's not duplicate
2. if a new item is added it done on top of the array

```
Schedule.update(
  { date: "10/4/2018" },
  { $addToSet: { games: <id> }},
  { upsert: true },
function(err, update){

})
```

Thanks,

Kris

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use the [$position](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) modifier for that:

```
Schedule.update(
  { date: "10/4/2018", games: { $nin: <id> } }, // exclude documents that already contain the <id> value
  { 
    $push: {
      games: {
        $each: [ <id> ],
        $position: 0 // push to first position
      }
    }
  },
  { upsert: true },
function(err, update){

})
```